# Posting json to the same page with fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

im trying to achieve something pretty simple, i just wanna post the form to itself without a refresh, however i require it to post the data from the form as it is captured by the controller. im getting the data in the back end i just need the form to post successfully without a refresh and then show and hide certain things. Also, i get this error

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

i presume this is why im not reaching my conditional

```
const wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.form-wrapper');

if (wrappers) {
wrappers.forEach(function(el){
    const form = el.querySelector('.submit-form');
    let currentURL = window.location.href;
    const output = el.nextElementSibling;

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        const data = new FormData(form);
        fetch(`${currentURL}`, {
            credentials: 'include',
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.success) {
                console.log('submitted');
                output.classList.remove('none');
                form.classList.add('none');
            }
            else if (res.error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + res.error); 
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    },false);
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `preventDefault` from the event object towards the beginning of your block:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

In the event that your POST request wasn't successful, supply a `catch` block:

```
fetch(`${currentURL}`, {
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: i need to check if its successful or not. if the post is good then show a thank you message etc i cant check with just preventDefault()

Comment: If the POST request wasn't successful that's where a `catch` block comes into play. Reload your location in there.

Comment: could you elaborate further or point me to a resource. i am still a junior in the js world. can you catch a success?

Comment: First things first. Are you able to get a successful response from what you have now?

Comment: with the code i have now. no i get an error. Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: I'm guessing that you're sending key/value pairs not formatted in json.

Comment: Try: `const data = JSON.stringify(new FormData(form));`

Comment: Try adding a `headers` object to the object you have now with the following key/value pairs:

Comment: `headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' }`

Comment: still a nope. :(

Comment: when you make the fetch request from script does it show in the network tab of your developer tools (press F12 in browser). What is the response code and what is the content of the response?

Comment: 200 with a type of fetch. the content of the response is the html for the page. i presume this is the issue